# What to expect of Inject in comparison to ManagedProperty

Tags: jsf, dependency-injection, cdi, jsf-2.2

I'm starting to use `Inject` instead of `ManagedProperty`. I have made some tests and in one of them, I inject a `ViewScoped` bean (`Bean1`) into another (`Bean2`) that has the same scope:

```
@Inject
private Bean1 bean1;
```

Bean1 has a variable `item` that represents an artist and the artist have a number of different fields like: name, a list of albums, etc.

In Bean2 I need to access the item in Bean1:

```
Artist artist = bean1.getItem();
```

When I set a breakpoint on that line to see what's inside `Bean1`, I can see the variable `item`, but when I expand `item`, no fields are set.

If I try to step into the `getItem()` method with the debugger, I get this message:

`Thread http-listener-1(2) stopped at beans.Bean1$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getItem - compiled without debug info.`

Stepping down one line with the debugger and then looking at the `artist` variable, all fields has been set to the correct values. How can that be? Before all was null.

**Edit1**: If I replace `Inject` with `ManagedProperty`, change from `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` to `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` and do the same steps in regard to debugging, I can see that the fields in `item` are set. I can also step into the method `getItem()`.

Comment: What is the actual problem here? Your bean is not being injected?

Comment: It seems to get injected, though later on I get null pointer exeception. My specific questions are why I can't see the fields in `item`, why I can't step into the method `getItem()` and why `artist` is eventually set anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from `@ManagedProperty` to `@Inject` you can expect to also forget about all the annotations in the `javax.faces.bean.*` package. The reason for it is that you can't mix the JSF's own dependency injection mechanism together with CDI, otherwise unexpected behavior will result.

Comment: This is not entirely accurate. With JSF2.2, `@ManagedBean` is now a valid target for `@Inject`.

Comment: It seems that you may be right. However, 2.2 JSF introduced a dependency on CDI with the new `ViewScoped` and `FlowScoped` annotations, albeit an optional one, so I take it as a sign that JSF is moving towards CDI. Also, the `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` got a deprecation warning in JSF 2.2.

Comment: You're correct that the JSF annotations are going to be eventually retired in favor of CDI annotations